# C++ glibc detected free(): invalid next size (fast)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gdb, valgrind, glibc

```
vector<priority_queue<Order, vector<Order>, sellCompare> > buyHeap;
buyHeap.resize(numEqs);

buyHeap[currentOrder.eqId].push(currentOrder);
```

I'm working on a project where, as stock orders come in, I want to push the orders onto a priority queue so that the highest asking prices are on top (my sellCompare comparator does this).  The program runs on an order by order basis and finishes when it doesn't see another order, so that third line runs however many times it needs to.

I create a vector of priority queues and resize it to fit the number of Equities I'm working with so whenever an order comes in on a certain equity I can just push it onto the appropriate priority queue.

I'm getting the error shown in the title at that third line after the 11th order and I'm not sure why. I know it's some sort of seg faulting error, and I found out it's happening at the third line by couting. But I've ruled out the [] indexing as a possible running-off-the-end problem with testing it using constants in the brackets and not variables.

This means all that's left is the buyHeap PQ is running off the end but I thought that wasn't possible. Don't PQs just reallocate size as items are pushed on?

I'm even more concerned because I've tried valgrind ./filename and GDB debugging and neither completes -- they both just sit there and I have to terminate the debugging manually in the terminal.

Any help?

Comment: Make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: A fairly likely problem is broken [strict weak ordering](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) in your `sellCompare`, but undefined behaviour anywhere in your program could be incidentally causing trouble with this particular code.  As Matt says - you need to provide more code - ideally MCVE.

Comment: Replace [] indexing with .at() method, it checks for boundaries, and run again